# Delegate Pattern : Delegate or Delegator?

Tags: terminology, design-patterns

I've a simple question about the terminology used in the Delegate pattern;

Let's say I create an object that will be responsible to download something from the Net and when it is finished, will call me back with the result. I guess we can call the downloader object the "delegate", since he is doing work on the behalf of my main object.

If I'm right 'til here, then, I've a problem with the sample codes I read. The property in the Downloader Class is often named "delegate", and put to Self by the creator of this downloader.

Am I wrong or it should effectively be called "delegator" instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *delegate* is the thing that is performing the sub-task. In your case, `Downloader` is doing the main task, but then tells the *delegate* to perform some task. `Downloader` does not know or care what that task is, just that it has to happen.

If you have to use *delegator*, it would be `Downloader` as it is the class that delegates work to something else. But I think that runs into problems because you have multiple words that are similar and lead to confusion like yours. Instead, I tend to think of things in terms of events and listeners. When `Downloader` finishes, it fires a `downloadFinished` event and tells any listeners that the event occurred. The listener than decides what it wants to do with that information.

Comment: Does it mean that I really get the pattern upside down ? To me, the main object is doing the main job, and ask to the "downloader" to do a side job and call him back when it's done. The main object creates a delegate, in that sense. But it seems I 'm wrong, isn't it ?

Comment: @Pierre: It all depends on the scope of what you are thinking. `Main` is doing a task and creates a `Downloader` to do a side task. But from the scope of `Downloader`, it is doing a task and notifying someone else when it finishes. `Main` doesn't care about what is inside `Downloader` and `Downloader` doesn't know `Main` exists. It is ok if they both have a `delegate` variable that do different things.